# Dotted transparent selection box appears after closing Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, windows-11, malware

When I close Microsoft Word files, this annoying dotted transparent selection box appears on my desktop home screen.

[image: Dotted Transparent Selection Example]

When I close any other file type, a translucent selection box appears, which seems much better.

[image: Translucent Selection Example]

How do I stop the dotted transparent borders from appearing? Could this be a sign of malware?

Comment: Are you opening files located inside a desktop folder called "Files"?

Comment: @harrymc yes I am

Comment: This folder was selected.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I realize the folder was selected. But why is it selected differently when I close a Word doc?